# nuget vs2015 Cannot Resolve Group Target Dependicies Correctly

Tags: visual-studio, nuget, nuget-spec

I use visual studio 2015 and when I want to use a nuget package(includes .netcore and .net versions both) from my .net45 project that time nuget package manager try to resolve .netcore depencies and failed.What I am waiting if my project is .net45 that time only try to resolve target framework 4.5 depencies but nuget try to resolve .NETStandard1.3 dependecies too. Am I missing something or is this design behaviour of nuget?

nuspec file like that

```
<dependencies>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.5">
        <dependency id="librdkafka.redist" version="0.11.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
      <group targetFramework=".NETFramework4.6">
        <dependency id="librdkafka.redist" version="0.11.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
      <group targetFramework=".NETStandard1.3">
        <dependency id="NETStandard.Library" version="1.6.1" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="librdkafka.redist" version="0.11.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="System.Console" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="System.Linq" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="System.Runtime.InteropServices" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="System.Runtime.Extensions" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
        <dependency id="System.Threading" version="4.3.0" exclude="Build,Analyzers" />
      </group>
    </dependencies>
```

Comment: According to your description, I create a sample package based on your dependencies. Please try install my package from below link: https://1drv.ms/u/s!AkHKK8SV6beshi6VjSOrxexDj0aD If it could install correct in your project, the problem should be related to your package. Otherwise, there has any problem in your Visual Studio 2015.

Comment: @Bilgehan, Can not reproduce. Could you share us more detail steps to reproduce this issue, your complete .nuspec file and what is the project type you installed on this package?

Comment: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Confluent.Kafka/ I try to use this file,can you download on your visual studio?

Comment: @Bilgehan, yes, I can download that package and it works fine for .NET framework 4.5 project. How did you install it and what is your project type? .NET framework? I have created a sample sample, you can check it, or you can share us a video how did you reproduce this issue. https://1drv.ms/i/s!Ai1sp_yvodHfeN8dmR0SOa4Awd0

Comment: I use visual studio nuget package manager screen,I can download it and I can use it when I upgrade my nuget version extension in my visual studio but my client who has older versions of nuget extensions failed because of .net core dependicies

Comment: @Bilgehan, What is the version of your older versions nuget extensions? Have you try to update it, then check if it works fine? If this issue still occur on the latest version, I think you may need to share us some detail steps to reproduce this issue.

Comment: Yes nuget 3.6 works fine but older versisons are (before 2.12 ) has problems

Answer (score 0):

> nuget vs2015 Cannot Resolve Group Target Dependicies Correctly

According to the troubleshooting on above comments, you need update your nuget extensions after the 2.12 version. **That because starting with nuget 2.12, nuget support full NetStandard and NetCoreApp**. You can refer to the [nuget release note for 2.12](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/nuget/release-notes/nuget-2.12-rc):

> •Full NetStandard and NetCoreApp support for VS2013

So, to resolve this issue, please update your nuget extensions first.